# Akka persistent query reader as competing consumer

Tags: scala, redis, akka, akka-persistence

I'm dabbling around with Akka and persistence query. Below design shows what I'm doing here.

When I run multiple instances of the "persistence reader actor", all the actors (#6 below) receive the same message. Ideally, I would want one of the actors to receive the message vs all. Is it possible to implement "competing consumers" so that I can avoid the same message being processed by multiple persistence reader actors?

I did go thru akka "smallest-mailbox-pool" to implement competing consumers but wanted to make sure that there is nothing inbuilt in persistence reader plugins before handling competing consumers with my own code.

[image]

Comment: can you please add some code samples to the question. How do you subscribe to the messages, how you produce messages? Thank you

Comment: I use Akka persistence and persistence query on the read side. Message sender produces message via http calls. Code is here https://github.com/sahas-/CQRS_HttpServer_Writemodel, https://github.com/sahas-/CQRS_aggregator

Comment: It seems like you are starting consumer(-s) in a separate process. And your consumer isn't an actor so is not receiving any messages, only reading from journal. You might want to look into [akka cluster](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/cluster-usage.html) and [cluster sharding](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/cluster-sharding.html)